# Hive on DSE 4.0 throwing NoSuchMethodError

Tags: hive, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.0

Getting this exception when using Hive on DSE 4.0.

Looks like the Hive version that is shipped with DSE 4.0 has a know issue
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6962

Does anyone have a workaround. I tried a few that were mentioned in the jira, that did not help

```
hive> SHOW TABLES;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.unset(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.createDirsWithPermission(Utilities.java:3416)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.createDirsWithPermission(Utilities.java:3401)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getScratchDir(Context.java:214)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getLocalScratchDir(Context.java:241)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getLocalTmpPath(Context.java:333)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:327)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:391)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:291)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:944)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1009)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:880)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:870)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:268)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:220)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:423)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:792)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:686)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSE 4.0 is shipped with 0.12.0 version, so if you use Hive 0.13.0, it will throws that exception